# Accessing Doorkeeper Application Information before login redirect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, helper, doorkeeper

**Explanation**

I am wanting to halt the authorization process of a client app (running OAuth2) coming to the parent app (running Doorkeeper) in order to see which client app is requesting a login. That way I can then look up the clientID and dynamically build a custom login screen for the client app. Right now, my client goes to parent, AuthorizationController is called, but before new is called and I can get the `params[:client_id]`,  `authenticate_resource_owner!` is called with a `before_action`. That then sends the user to the login page if they are not already logged in with the parent. So, before I can get the param, it is being redirected.

**Question**

The `authenticate_resource_owner!` is held in a Doorkeeper helper file. I thought that I set it up correctly to bypass the default helper and go to mine where I can try and grab the param and save in sessions before the redirect, but I guess my route is not set up correctly and I can't find any documentation on how to correctly call it. Can anyone help?

**Code**

Code for setting up the client:

```
def setup_client
    @client = Application.find_by(uid: params[:client_id])
    session[:client_name] = @client.name
    authenticate_resource_owner!
end
```

I know that the first 2 lines work as I placed them in the `CustomAuthorizationsController` with a `byebug` and it triggered after the login and before redirect back to client and showed the client name stored in a session variable.

In my `config/routes.rb`

```
  use_doorkeeper do
    controllers :applications   => 'doorkeeper/custom_applications'
    controllers :authorizations => 'doorkeeper/custom_authorizations'
    helpers     :doorkeeper     => 'doorkeeper/doorkeeper'
  end
```

Helper file is located in `app/helpers/doorkeeper/doorkeeper_helper.rb`

**Error**

When I start up my server I get:

```
: from ~/ruby-2.5.0/gems/doorkeeper-5.0.2/lib/doorkeeper/rails/routes/mapper.rb:12:in `instance_eval'
~/settingsParentApp/config/routes.rb:65:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>': undefined method `helpers' for #<Doorkeeper::Rails::Routes::Mapper:0x00007ffd539b9c10> (NoMethodError)
```

**Conclusion**

Am I even doing this right? Is there a simpler way built into Doorkeeper that I am not seeing to get this information to customize the login screen? Or is there some error that I am not seeing in how I am calling the helper file?

Comment: Solution found. Posting answer now.

Answer (score 2):

After thinking through my problem in order to ask this question, a solution dawned on me. I tested it out and it worked. I forgot that in a controller, the `before_action` statements are called in the order they are presented. So, my solution was just to reorder my statements to call the `setup_client` first before the `authenticate_resource_owner!`. This set up the session variable before redirecting to the login screen and then allowed me to have the variable available for use.

**Code**

Within my `config/routes.rb` file:

```
  use_doorkeeper do
    controllers :applications   => 'doorkeeper/custom_applications'
    controllers :authorizations => 'doorkeeper/custom_authorizations'
  end
```

This custom route bypasses the doorkeeper default authorization controller and goes to a custom one which inherits from the default controller. So, all I need within this custom one is this code:

Found: `app/controllers/doorkeeper/custom_authorizations_controller.rb`

```
module Doorkeeper
  class CustomAuthorizationsController < Doorkeeper::AuthorizationsController
    before_action :setup_client
    before_action :authenticate_resource_owner!

    def setup_client
        @client = Application.find_by(uid: params[:client_id])
        session[:client_name] = @client.name
    end

  end
end
```

This code is then run before it looks to the Doorkeeper's default `AuthorizationsController` and thus calls `setup_client` first. The session variable is then saved and in the login screen I can call it this way:

```
<% 
  if session[:client_name].nil?
    @client_name = ''
  else
    @client_name = ' for ' + session[:client_name]
  end

  @page_name = "Login" + @client_name
%>
```

And then in header of the page I call this within the HTML:

```
<h1><%= @page_name %></h1>
```

I may do more fancy things later, like saving client icons/logos and color schemes to make branding specific on the login page, but for now, this basic issue has been resolved. Thank you all for acting as my sounding board and problem-solving ducks... if you know of that reference. :-) Happy Coding!

Comment: Could also use `prepend_before_action :setup_client` and then you don't need to include `before_action :authenticate_resource_owner!` in your custom controller